# Shopify Dashing: How do I include external Javascript? (e.g Raphael.js)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, raphael, dashing

I'm putting together a [Shopify Dashing](http://dashing.io/) widget that will use the [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) library to draw SVG objects on the client (i.e. dashboard).

I have the code working in a standalone manner in pure JavaScript, rendering everything I need.

However, now I need to import the Raphael.js library in the widget's **.coffee** file, and am really struggling with this.

Does anyone know how to include external JavaScript libraries from within a Dashing widget's code?

Answer (score 0):

This got answered for me on the Dashing GitHub page - see link here: https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/393#event-137431060